# Python - Pandas - resample issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to adapt a Pandas.Series with a certain frequency to a Pandas.Series with a different frequency. Therefore I used the resample function but it does not recognize for instance that 'M' is a subperiod of '3M' and raised an error

```
import pandas as pd

idx_1 = pd.period_range('2017-01-01', periods=6, freq='M')
data_1  = pd.Series(range(6), index=idx_1)
data_higher_freq = data_1.resample('3M', kind="Period").sum()
```

Raises the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/home/mitch/Programs/Infrastructure_software/Sandbox/spyderTest.py", line 15, in <module>
data_higher_freq = data_1.resample('3M', kind="Period").sum() File "/home/mitch/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 758, in f return self._downsample(_method, min_count=min_count) File "/home/mitch/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/resamplepy", line 1061, in _downsample 'sub or super periods'.format(ax.freq, self.freq))
pandas._libs.tslibs.period.IncompatibleFrequency: Frequency <MonthEnd> cannot be resampled to <3 * MonthEnds>, as they are not sub or super periods
```

This seems to be due to the pd.tseries.frequencies.is_subperiod function:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.tseries.frequencies.is_subperiod('M', '3M')
pd.tseries.frequencies.is_subperiod('M', 'Q')
```

Indeed it returns False for the first command  and True for the second.

I would really appreciate any hints about any solution.

Thks.

Comment: `pd.tseries.frequencies.is_subperiod('M', '3M')` gives me a `Nonetype` instead of `bool`. But resamples fine for me. I am running python 3.6.

Comment: To clarify, I am running python 3.6 as well with Pandas 0.23.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing from `PeriodIndex` to `DateTimeIndex` before resampling:

```
import pandas as pd

idx_1 = pd.period_range('2017-01-01', periods=6, freq='M')
data_1  = pd.Series(range(6), index=idx_1)
data_1.index = data_1.index.astype('datetime64[ns]')
data_higher_freq = data_1.resample('3M', kind='period').sum()
```

Output:

```
data_higher_freq
Out[582]: 
2017-01     3
2017-04    12
Freq: 3M, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I believe I will have to use this kind of operations to switch back and forth between datetime and period then. pands